# How to edit pivoted table Checkbox Data in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am trying to edit and update pivoted table data, but i am unable to edit. I have `belongsToMany` relation between `listings` and `project_types` tables.

Here are my Listing.php model...

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Listing;
use App\ProjectType;
class Listing extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'lstId';
protected $guarded = [];

public function proType(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProjectType::class, 'properties_searchable_tags', 'lstId', 'typeId');
}
}
```

here are my ProjectType.php model...

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\City;
use App\Listing;
use App\ProjectType;

class ProjectType extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $primaryKey = 'typeId';
protected $guarded = [];
protected $with = ['listing'];

public function propertytype(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectType::class, 'ctId','ctId');
}

public function listing()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProjectType::class, 'properties_searchable_tags','typeId','lstId');
}
}
```

Here are my ProjectTypeContrroller.php file..

```
 public function edit($projectType)
{
    $city=City::all();
    $locality=Locality::all();
    $listingdata=Listing::all();
    $propertyType=ProjectType::findOrFail($projectType);
    return view('admin.propertytype.edit', compact('city', 'propertyType','locality','listingdata'));
}
```

Here are my edit.blade.php

```
    <tbody>
                                            @foreach($listingdata as $lists)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 10%">
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="{{$lists->proptype}}" id="proptype[0]" value="{{$lists->typeId}}">
                                                        }
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{$lists->prop_name}}</td>
                                            @if($lists->property->builder)
                                            <td>{{$lists->property->builder->name}}</td>
                                            @endif
                                            <td>{{$lists->property->proLocation->locations}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$lists->property->proLocality->name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems propertytype() relation in your projectType model is wrong because it's saying ProjectType belongsTo ProjectType, which it's not a relation and need to be removed.

Also your listing relation should be something similar to:

```
public function listing()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Listing::class, 'properties_searchable_tags','typeId','lstId');
}
```

Your edit controller/view is just for rendering and compact the data from controller to view, for update you need "Update" function and another route with "POST" method and of course a form in your view.

if you are not going to use form in your view, then you may want to use AJAX update which you still need to "Update" function in your controller and a route which accepting "POST" method for that.